# More than one value to PIVOT in chronological order

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, pivot

I would like help in how to think and order this SQL problem, not necessarily with the actual code.

I have a large table of background checks my fields are:

```
[First Name]
[Last Name]
[SSN]
[Administration]    // Who conducted the background check
[Date of Birth]     // This field is often null
[Result]            // Possible values are 'No Record', 'Record', or Null
[ResultDate]
```

Most people have more than one background check. For example, John Doe could have one background by Administration X on 1/1/2011 and another by Administration Y on 1/1/2012.

I would like to `PIVOT` the Result, ResultDate, and Administration together in chronologically order. For example the record would read

```
John Doe - 'Record' - 1/1/2011 - Administration X - 'Record' on 1/1/2013
```

I can't seem to figure out how to do this. How would you pivot based on three different fields? If you can pivot based on three different fields (Result, ResultDate, Administration) can you order these chronologically based on ResultDate?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `row_number` to sort your Result Dates by Name and SSN and concatenate your Result, Result Date, and Administration columns:

```
-- load sample data
if object_id('tempdb..#background_checks','u') is not null
    drop table #background_checks
create table #background_checks
    (
    [First Name] varchar(50),
    [Last Name] varchar(50),
    [SSN] char(11),
    [Administration] varchar(50),
    [Result] varchar(50),
    [Result Date] date
    )
insert into #background_checks
    values
        ('John','Doe',NULL,'Administration X','Record','2011-01-01'),
        ('John','Doe',NULL,'Administration Y','Record','2012-01-01'),
        ('John','Doe',NULL,'Administration Z','No Record','2013-01-01')

-- pivot results
select
    [First Name],
    [Last Name],
    [1] as [Result 1],
    [2] as [Result 2],
    [3] as [Result 3]
from (select
        [First Name],
        [Last Name],
        [Result] + ' - ' +
            convert(varchar(10),[Result Date],101) + ' - ' +
            [Administration] as [Result],
        row_number() over(partition by [First Name],[Last Name],[SSN]
            order by [Result Date]) as ColumnID
      from #background_checks) t
      pivot (
            max([Result]) for ColumnID in([1],[2],[3])
            ) p1
```